# Keeping 2 digits after decimal without rounding off

Tags: r

`data <- c(28.9899,23.565444,98.8999,34.8788)`

The expected output is: `28.98, 23.56, 98.89, 34.87`

Comment: another one `floor(data * 100) / 100` and `sprintf('%.2f', floor(data * 100) / 100)` to keep trailing 0s

Answer (score 8):

Basic R `floor` function doesn't allow decimal number so let's define

```
floor_decimal <- function(x, level=1) round(x - 5*10^(-level-1), level)
```

then by

```
floor_decimal(data,2)
```

returns

```
[1] 28.98 23.56 98.89 34.87
```

Comment: Best solution as it doesn't involve casting to a character vector.

Comment: Best solution by far

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is for displaying purpose you may use regex to extract data only till 2 decimal places.

```
sub('(\\d+\\.\\d{2}).*', '\\1', data)
#[1] "28.98" "23.56" "98.89" "34.87"
```

Answer (score 2):

Cut unwanted digits using regex and re-convert to numeric:

```
as.numeric(sub("(.*\\.\\d{2}).*", "\\1", data))
[1] 28.98 23.56 98.89 34.87
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `trunc()`:

```
trunc(data*100)/100
```

Output:

```
[1] 28.98 23.56 98.89 34.87
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(stringi)
data<- c(28.9899,23.565444,98.8999,34.8788) 
as.numeric(stri_sub(data,1,5))
```

output

```
28.98 23.56 98.89 34.87
```